# reading and formatting a text file in ansi c

Tags: c, io

I'm learning C and one of the tasks it to read in a text file, and have it output a formatted text file. The final product should look like this:

```
1)"I must not fear.[4,17]
2)Fear is the mind-killer.[4,24]
3)Fear is the little-death that brings total obliteration.[8,56]
4)I will face my fear.[5,20]
.
.
.
13)oneWord_allAlone[1,16]
13 lines, 94 words, 481 characters
Line 10 has the most words (16)
Line 7 has the most characters (68)
```

I've written the code and can get something close-ish, but the information is out of order and the variables are wrong and it cuts off the first letter of each sentence. I get:

```
I must not fear0.) 
[4, 16]
ear is the mind-killer.0) 
[7 39]
ear is the little-death that brings total obliteration.0) 
[14 92]
.
.
.
neWord_allAlone1)
[86 470] 
1 lines, 20360 words, 110685 characters
line 1 has the most words with (86)
line 1 has the most characters with 470)
```

Where it is getting 110685 characters is beyond me. So, with that said, what am I doing wrong? As far as I can tell, I have all the variables set up properly, but the output is in the wrong order, the first character is being cut off, and the counts are wayyyy off. Any help is much appreciated! Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define IN 1
#define OUT 0

void main() {

  int c = 0;
  int numChars = 0;
  int numWords = 0;
  int numLines = 0;
  int state = OUT;
  int test = 0;
  int largestNumChars = 0;
  int largestNumWords = 0;
  int totalNumChars = 0; 
  int totalNumWords = 0;
  int lineWithMostChars = 0;
  int lineWithMostWords = 0;

  FILE *doesthiswork = fopen("testWords.in", "r");
  while ((test = fgetc(doesthiswork)) != EOF) {
    if ( test == '\n') {
            ++numLines;
    }
    while ((test = fgetc(doesthiswork)) != '\n') {    
        ++numChars;
        putchar(test);   
        if (test == ' ' || test == '\t' || test == '\n') {      
          state = OUT;
        } else if (state == OUT){
          state = IN;
          ++numWords;          
        }
        totalNumWords = totalNumWords + numWords;
        totalNumChars = totalNumChars + numChars;    
     }

     if (largestNumChars == 0)  {
       largestNumChars = numChars;
     } else if (largestNumChars < numChars) {
       largestNumChars = numChars;
       lineWithMostChars = numLines;
     } else  {
       largestNumChars = largestNumChars;
       lineWithMostChars = lineWithMostChars;
     }

     if (largestNumWords == 0)  {
       largestNumWords = numWords;
       lineWithMostWords = numLines;
     } else if (largestNumWords < numWords) {
       largestNumWords = numWords;
       lineWithMostWords = lineWithMostWords;
     } else {
       largestNumWords = largestNumWords;
     }

     printf("%d) %c [%d %d]\n",numLines, test, numWords, numChars);
   }

   printf("%d lines, %d words, %d characters\n", 
     numLines, totalNumWords, totalNumChars);
   printf("line %d has the most words with (%d)\n", 
     lineWithMostWords, largestNumWords);
   printf("line %d has the most characters with (%d)\n", 
     lineWithMostChars, largestNumChars);  
}
```

Comment: If you want anybody else to be able to read your code (as opposed to throwing their hands up in despair), *please* align your indents consistently and correctly. For example, it's not at all clear at first glance where your second `while` loop ends.

Comment: What is `FILE *doesthiswork doesthiswork = fopen("testWords.in", "r");` all about? I don't think this is your real code.

Comment: That actually is my real code. I named the output file doesthiswork because I was unsure if it would work and needed a file name.

Comment: and I apologize for my terrible formatting.

Comment: If that's your real code, it won't compile, and won't produce any output at all.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: That was an error [introduced by FoggyDay](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25597737/revisions) during a code indent cleanup and the original code was correct.

Comment: @GregHewgill: Well spotted, I fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, where the initial letters are going is that you're reading them with the first `fgetc` call, but you don't `putchar` them like you do with the second `fgetc` call.

And `totalNumChars` is so large because you periodically add `numChars` to it, but you don't ever reset `numChars` back to zero.

I hope this helps. Have fun finding and squishing those bugs!

Answer (score 0):

First, you `putchar()` the letters before the line number. Then, in the second `while`, the `test` always store the `'\n'`, so the `[numWords, numChars]` always at the next line of the letters. As @aecolley said, the `numWords`, `numChars` should be reseted back to zero.

```
lineWithMostWords = lineWithMostWords;
```

should be

```
 lineWithMostWords = numLines;
```

This is my code, maybe help you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>

#define IN      1
#define OUT     0
#define MAXLINE 500

void main()
{
    int numChars = 0;
    int numWords = 0;
    int numLines = 0;
    int state = OUT;
    int test = 0;
    int largestNumChars = 0;
    int largestNumWords = 0;
    int totalNumChars = 0;
    int totalNumWords = 0;
    int lineWithMostChars = 0;
    int lineWithMostWords = 0;
    char line[MAXLINE+1], *lineTemp;
    int lineLen;

    FILE *doesthiswork;
    doesthiswork = fopen("testWords.in", "r");
    while (fgets(line, MAXLINE, doesthiswork) != NULL)
    {
        numChars = 0;
        numWords = 0;
        lineLen = strlen(line);
        line[lineLen - 1] = '\0';
        lineTemp = line;
        state = OUT;

        ++numLines;

        while ((test = *lineTemp++) != '\0')
        {
            ++numChars;

            if (test == ' ' || test == '\t')
            {
                state = OUT;
            }
            else if (state == OUT){
                state = IN;
                ++numWords;
            }
        }

        totalNumWords = totalNumWords + numWords;
        totalNumChars = totalNumChars + numChars;

        if (largestNumChars == 0)
        {
            largestNumChars = numChars;
         }
        else if (largestNumChars < numChars)
        {
            largestNumChars = numChars;
            lineWithMostChars = numLines;
        }

        if (largestNumWords == 0)
        {
            largestNumWords = numWords;
            lineWithMostWords = numLines;
        }
        else if (largestNumWords < numWords)
        {
            largestNumWords = numWords;
            lineWithMostWords = numLines;
        }

        printf("%d) %s [%d %d]\n",numLines, line, numWords, numChars);
    }
    printf("%d lines, %d words, %d characters\n", numLines, totalNumWords, totalNumChars);
    printf("line %d has the most words with (%d)\n", lineWithMostWords, largestNumWords);
    printf("line %d has the most characters with (%d)\n", lineWithMostChars,     largestNumChars);
}
```